# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Expected URL scheme 'http' or 'https' but no scheme was found for /

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, retrofit

I was developing an app with make some API call using Retrofit, but the object of the request and the response are not JSON, but XML.

So I get a try to SimpleXMLConverter, which I saw is deprecate, but the other solution: JABX is not working on Android.

I try to implemented like this:

build.gradle.app:

```
 //SimpleXmlConverterFactory excluding some modules, to avoid compilation errors
    implementation('com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-simplexml:2.9.0') {
        exclude module: 'stax'
        exclude module: 'stax-api'
        exclude module: 'xpp3'
    }
    //url: https://etemnogrudova.medium.com/parsing-xml-using-retrofit2-in-kotlin-8e0ff6420bd7
```

So I don't know if ir's relate with the fact of using XML, but when I make the API call using retroit a get the following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Expected URL scheme 'http' or 'https' but no scheme was found for /
```

This exception rise when A try to inyect the API using hilt into my LoginUseCase,so rise in the buiding of the API, which is the `following:

```
interface PayAtTableApi {
    //TODO: Fix endpoints: Pass as XML type parameters
    @POST("")
    suspend fun login(@Body loginRequest: LoginRequestDTO? = null): Response<LoginResponseDTO>

    @POST("")
    suspend fun checkOutInfo(@Body checkOutInfoRequest: GetCheckInfoRequestDTO? = null): Response<GetCheckInfoResponseDTO>

    @POST("")
    suspend fun postPayment(@Body postPaymentRequestDTO: PostPaymentRequestDTO? = null): Response<PostPaymentResponseDTO>

    @POST("")
    suspend fun disconnect(@Body disconnectRequest: DisconnectRequestDTO? = null): Response<DisconnectResponseDTO>
}
```

Perhaps is an error in the way I'm telling Retrofit which the request is, because I shouldn't use @Body as annotation.

So, if you have experience which some similar issue try to use xml as request and response of an API call with Retrofit, and can help, take thanks in advance !